# Unauthorized CSRF validation failed in jMeter testing

Tags: jmeter, csrf, django-csrf

I'm new to jMeter testing. I want to test the field update on UI. So When I run my test I'm getting the CSRF validation error. How can I resolve this. My test plan looks as,

[image]

And the sampler result is as follows,

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2014-11-18 23:37:49 IST
Load time: 688
Latency: 688
Size in bytes: 483
Headers size in bytes: 457
Body size in bytes: 26
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized : CSRF validation failed

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized : CSRF validation failed
Date: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 18:08:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 18:08:07 +0000
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
ETag: "1416334087"
Vary: Accept
Content-Length: 26
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

Why do we get CSRF validation error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSRF stands for [Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and you're getting CSRF Validation error due to missing mandatory dynamic request parameter, usually a Cookie or a Header.

I would suggest executing your scenario in i.e. [Firefox Browser](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) with [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) or [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) extension enabled and inspect request details. CSRF token usually comes as a cookie in server's response and needs to be passed as a header or request parameter. So it is similar to usual correlation. So the flow should look as follows:

1. First HTTP Request: open first page
2. Extract CSRF token from response via one of the following Post Processors

   - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
   - [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
   - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
3. Second HTTP Request: open second page (CSRF-protected). Add the token, extracted in step 2 to one of the following:

   - HTTP Request Parameter
   - [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
   - [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

Depending on where your server expects the token to live.

For the future, looking at your "localhost" server name - don't run JMeter performance tests on the same machine where application lives.

Comment: I will try to do it using firebug extension and let you know the status

Comment: Now I'm not working on local host, I have separate testing server. I made a request, but How can I extract the CSRF token response (Step 2). Iam using blaze meter plugin so I am able to see the all header details including "X-CSRF-Token". I have added the HTTP Header Manager to step1. Please help me how can I do htat

Comment: We need to see your recording details to be able to assist and suggest the best way of extracting the token and passing it to server.

Comment: I tried recording using blaze meter, will that be okay right? or should I need to use any other other recording process. Please let me know more about this please