# I am facing below given error while playing recorded script in jmeter for MOBILE APP TESTING. How can I move forward to resolve this?

Tags: mobile, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

View result tree "RESULT"

=================

**Sample result:**

```
Sample Start: 2014-11-19 12:02:04 IST
Load time: 4
Latency: 4
Size in bytes: 565
Headers size in bytes: 399
Body size in bytes: 166
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized
```

**Response Data:**

```
/*-secure-
{"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"s79n1telbac8m4lg0vsttj50am"},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"token":"93mj6dsa7k92udvn95gd27kq16"}}}*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a CSRF protection challenge, it was already asked today:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27011561/2897748

Comment: This is for mobile application. I am not clear with given URL